# String find function in C++ returns 0 if string passed as argument is empty

Tags: c++, stdstring

When a empty string is passed to find function it returns 0.

If uninitialized string is passed, then also it returns 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str1="";
    string str2="This is a sample string";
    unsigned int loc = str2.find(str1);
    cout << "Loc : " << loc << endl;
    if(loc != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "Found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** :

Loc : 0

Found

My question is why does find return 0 instead of returning string::npos ?

Comment: for the records, the empty string is equivalent to an uninitialized one.

Comment: after `string str1;` `str1` is initialized; the default constructor is used to initialize the string which happens to initialize it as the empty string. It's rather hard to get an uninitialized string. you'll need to jump some hoops to get an uninitialized string: `void* memory = std::malloc(sizeof(std::string)); std::string* uninitializedStringPointer = static_cast<std::string*>(memory);`

Answer (score 5):

A needle `l` can be found in position `i` of haystack `h` if `i + len(l) <= len(h)` and for all `0 <= k < len(l)` we have `l[k] == h[i+k]`. What you're dealing with is simply the [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) of this definition: 'for all *x*' automatically becomes true if there's no valid *x* to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) say. (Emphasis is mine.)

> Finds the **first** substring equal to the given character sequence. Search begins at pos, i.e. the found substring must not begin in a position preceding pos.
>
> 1. Finds the first substring equal to `str`.

When is a string found at a position?

> Formally, a substring str is said to be found at position xpos if all of the following is true:
>
> - `xpos >= pos`
> - `xpos + str.size() <= size()`
> - for all positions `n` in `str`, `Traits::eq(at(xpos+n), str.at(n))`

An empty string fulfills these requirements at position 0.

The docs further say. (Emphasis is mine.)

> In particular, this implies that
>
> - a substring can be found only if `pos <= size() - str.size()`
> - **an empty substring is found at `pos` if and only if `pos <= size()`**
> - for a non-empty substring, if `pos >= size()`, the function always returns `npos`.

Comment: it isnt mentioned explicitly, though "for all positions n in str, Traits::eq(at(xpos+n), str.at(n))" implies that an empty substring can by found anywhere, because its size is 0, hence anything is true for any position in the substring

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The docs say that `find` finds the **first** substring.

Answer (score 1):

It found the exact match at position 0 (the first one searched), so that index is returned.

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), the conditions are:

> Formally, a substring `str` is said to be found at position `xpos` if all of the following is true:
>
> 1. `xpos >= pos`
> 2. `xpos + str.size() <= size()`
> 3. for all positions `n` in `str`, `Traits::eq(at(xpos+n), str.at(n))`

Trying to match substring from position 0, we get that

1. is met, because 0 (our search position) >= 0 (start parameter)
2. is met, because 0 + 0 <= size()
3. is met, because there is no character in the needle that doesn't match the corresponding character in haystack - all of them match.